# Can primefaces calendar make past dates and times disabled?

Tags: javascript, calendar, primefaces

I'm trying to make a calendar popup on a website to allow the user to pick a date.  This is for a reminder/task implementation.  I do not want the user to be able to select a previous date or time.

All that anyone has given for advice to this question is `mindate="today (get new Date())"`.  Which is great, because it makes previous days not able to be selected.  However, people could still choose a time of the day today, that is previous to right now.  So, one would naturally pick `minHour` and `minMinute`, but those retain for future days as well.  So if I have all 3 of those set, we get close, but the issue is, if I select a date of tomorrow, it will only allow times of day based off of `minMinute` and `minHour`, which are based off of your system time of `"today (get new Date())"`.  You should be able to select any time you want tomorrow.

Can I make the calendar only valid for days and times after "right now"??

This seems like a natural setting.  `futureDates="disabled"`, `pastDates="disabled"`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess doing all of this in the same calendar component is not possible by default. As it requires that you change the values of `minHour` and `minMinute` after the user has picked a date. Which means the calendar component needs to render again.

You could divide this into two components: One for only picking the date and another one for picking the time.

Then you can do an ajax call when the user selects a date and rerender the time component based on the selected date and set the `minHour` and `minMinute` according to the chosen date.

This is what the xhtml could look like:

```
<p:calendar id="dateOnly" mindate="#{datePickerView.minDate}"
    value="#{datePickerView.chosenDate}">

    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{datePickerView.handleDateSelect}" update="timeOnly" />  
</p:calendar>

<br />

<p:calendar id="timeOnly" value="#{datePickerView.chosenTime}" 
    pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" minHour="#{datePickerView.minHour}" 
    minMinute="#{datePickerView.minMinute}" />
```

And this is what the bean could look like:

```
public class DatePickerView implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date chosenDate;
    private Date chosenTime;

    public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
        chosenDate = event.getDate();
    }

    public Date getMinDate() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    public int getMinHour() {
        if (chosenDate.after(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        }
    }

    public int getMinMinute() {
        if (chosenDate.after(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }
    }

    public Date getChosenDate() {
        return chosenDate;
    }

    public void setChosenDate(Date chosenDate) {
        this.chosenDate = chosenDate;
    }

    public Date getChosenTime() {
        return chosenTime;
    }

    public void setChosenTime(Date chosenTime) {
        this.chosenTime = chosenTime;
   }
}
```

You should of course add timezone handling and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought of breaking this up too, but I didn't want to add more clicks for the user.  Might have to in the end.  The implementation is, choose frequency of reminder from the drop down, ie daily weekly or one time.  Then, based off of the selection I render a calendar that will show only time for daily, and a full calendar for weekly or one time.  Adding another selection would probably not go over well with the designer, and would also cause me to concatenate the date strings for the reminder deployment job that will run on intervals.  Again, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Maybe you can suggest your idea of controlling this via attributes (`futureDates="disabled"`) as an additional feature to the calendar component on the primefaces pages?

Comment: I tried getting on there but was having issues?!?  I created an account, but it keeps locking up.  Says my account is not active and won't allow searching on the site.  No idea what's going on there, but yes I could suggest this as an additional feature, just doesn't help much right now.

Comment: I have created a "new feature request" ticket at primefaces issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4630 (could not find a way to label this a feature request though).